# Pass DBContext to EfContextProvider in Breeze

Tags: breeze

I have an existing WebAPI project that resolves the database connection string to use and then uses Unity for dependency injection of a repository into APIControllers.  I would like to pass an instance of my DBContext to EFContextProvider instead of it creating another (1 per request).

What would be the ramifications if we added a public contructor that took a DBContext as assigned it to _context in the EFContextProvider class?

Comment: Looking for the same thing. I override the CreateContext to not new up the context, which makes injection possible, but then it causes problems when using the context via a business layer. Since the injected context in the business layer does not have the Breeze post creation settings applied, so the business layer returns proxy entities.